# How to validate Laravel 5.4 radio button?

Tags: php, forms, laravel, validation, radio-button

How can I validate my radio button in Laravel 5.4?

```
<div class="radio">
    <label><input name="gander" type="radio" value="male">male </label>
    <label><input name="gander" type="radio" value="female">female</label>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
/* Validate this form. */
$this->validate(request(), [
    'title' => 'required',
    'body' => 'required',
    'gander' => 'in:male,female'
]);

$post = new Post;
$post->title = $request['title'];
$post->body = $request['body'];
$post->status = $request['status'];
$post->male = $request['male'];
$post->female = $request['female'];
$post->save();

return redirect('blog');
```

When I submit the form, I get the following error.

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'male'
> cannot be null (SQL: insert into `posts` (`title`, `body`, `status`,
> `male`, `female`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (sdf, sdfsfsd, 0,
> , , 2017-03-01 13:09:54, 2017-03-01 13:09:54))

That means that both of radio buttons' data need for database field. and into my table have these fields: 'title', 'body', 'status', 'male', 'female' 'created_at' & 'updated_at'.

My problem is how to validate the radio button and how to insert data with the radio button value?

Comment: why do you have two diff fields for `male` and `female` ??? can you elaborate? you can simply take one field `gender`. and fill the value whether it is male or female. your way is WRONG!! BIG NO

Comment: tnx prakash for showing my wrong ,. now i create my schema field by tinyinteger data type. and now its works.

Comment: great!!! good luck

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If gender is a required field then you should also pass required validation to gander property like below

```
'gander'=> 'required|in:male,female'
```

If it is not a required field then make the `male` column nullable in your database table.

And there is also a problem in your table design instead of putting male value to male and female value to female make on column with name gender and type boolean then set `0` for `male` and `1` for `female`.

If you don't want to use boolean then use enum datatype for gender.enum is the best option in your case.

Comment: there is a problem in your table design make one enum column with name gender with values "male" and "female" instead of putting seperate column for male and female

Comment: how can I set type boolean as male to 0 and female to 1?

Answer (score 0):

The error message has nothing to do with the validation. The validation is passed and you do it properly. But your model seems weird, because instead of same "gender" column you have the male and female ones.

Comment: so whats my solution?

Comment: The solution is to change your model and table schema and replace two columns "male" and "female" with just one called "gender". Enum would be perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You can validate in the client-side just by adding the required attribute

```
<!-- Gender Field -->
<div class="form-group col-sm-6">
    {!! Form::label('gender', 'Gender: *') !!}
    <br>
    <label class="radio-inline">
        {!! Form::radio('gender', "Male", null,['required']) !!} Male
    </label>

    <label class="radio-inline">
        {!! Form::radio('gender', "Female", null) !!} Female
    </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Radio required featured works with laravel:

```
@foreach($status_list as $status_key => $status)

  {!! Form::radio('status', $status_key, false, array('id'=>'status_'.$status_key, 'required'=>'required' )); !!}

  {!! Form::label('status_'.$status_key, $status ) !!}

@endforeach
```

Comment: Zoe, It works for me. Thanks for devoting my comment. Kindly share right solution, if you are right.