# Validation Radio Button Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel

Hi this is courious  I dont understand how I can validate a radio input, I have validated other inputs with laravel, but Radio no. Of course  I am Laravel Beginner.  When  I don't filled the framework not give error to print. So formaPago is not validated. Cheers.
This is the HTML:

```
   <table class="table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            @foreach($formasPago as $forma)
                            <th><div class="form-check" >
                                    <label for="formaPago" class="form-check-label"></label>
                                     <input type="radio"
                                        class="form-check-input"  value="{{$forma->id}}"
                                        name="formaPago"   >{{$forma->nombre}}
                                </div></th> @endforeach
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
```

And the Validator in controller looks this way:

```
  $validator = \Validator::make($request->all(), [
                'nombreCompleto'=> 'required|string|max:255',
                'email'=>  Session::has('clientePotencial')?'required|string|email|max:255':'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
                'celular'=> 'required',
                'cedula'=> 'required',
        'primaria'=> 'required',
        'secundaria'=> 'required',
        'referencia'=> 'required',
        'formaPago'=> 'required|filled'
    ]);
```

Comment: You are not printing the error in your blade file though?

Comment: From your blade view it looks as though the radio input will always have a non null value since you supply it an id, `value="{{$forma->id}}"`, so it will always pass your validation.

Comment: Please try this.
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42532823/how-to-validate-laravel-5-4-radio-button][1]

Answer (score 0):

Set name attribute for radio button

```
@foreach($formasPago as $forma)
                        <th><div class="form-check" >
                                <label for="formaPago" class="form-check-label"></label>
                                 <input type="radio" name="formaPago"
                                    class="form-check-input"  value="{{$forma->id}}"
                                    name="formaPago"   >{{$forma->nombre}}
                            </div></th> @endforeach
```

get list of valid values and add below rule in validation

```
$validValues = //....get value from db

'gander'=> 'required|in:'.implode(",",$validValues);
```